# Circle animation random color

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas

Hi I try to create an animation with a circle. The function `drawRandom(drawFunctions)` should pic one of the three drawcircle functions and should bring it on the canvas. Now the problem is that this function become executed every second (main loop) and the circle change his colour. How can I fix that?

```
    window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  var C = 1; // canvas width to viewport width ratio
  var el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");


  var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

  var canvasWidth = viewportWidth * C;
  var canvasHeight = viewportHeight;
  el.style.position = "fixed";
  el.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
  el.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);
  var x = canvasWidth / 100;
  var y = canvasHeight / 100;
var ballx = canvasWidth / 100;
var n;


  window.ctx = el.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  // draw triangles


  function init() {
        ballx;      
        return setInterval(main_loop, 1000);
  }
  function drawcircle1()
  {
  var radius = x * 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 108, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      ctx.fill(); 
  }
function drawcircle2()
  {
  var radius = x * 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 108, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
      ctx.fill(); 
  }
  function drawcircle3()
  {
  var radius = x * 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 105, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
      ctx.fill(); 
  }

  function draw() {   
        var counterClockwise = false;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    //first halfarc
   ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x * 80, y * 80, y * 10, 0 * Math.PI, 1 * Math.PI, counterClockwise);
    ctx.lineWidth = y * 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();





    // draw stop button
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x * 87, y * 2);
      ctx.lineTo(x * 87, y * 10);
      ctx.lineWidth = x;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x * 95, y * 2);
      ctx.lineTo(x * 95, y * 10);
      ctx.lineWidth = x;
      ctx.stroke();


      function drawRandom(drawFunctions){
    //generate a random index
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drawFunctions.length);

    //call the function
    drawFunctions[randomIndex]();
}
drawRandom([drawcircle1, drawcircle2, drawcircle3]);


  }

  function update() {
    ballx -= 0.1;


    if (ballx < 0) {
      ballx = -radius;         


    }

  }







  function main_loop() {
    draw();
    update();
    collisiondetection();

  }


  init();

            function initi() {
                console.log('init');
                // Get a reference to our touch-sensitive element
                var touchzone = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                // Add an event handler for the touchstart event
                touchzone.addEventListener("mousedown", touchHandler, false);
            }

            function touchHandler(event) {
                // Get a reference to our coordinates div
                var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                // Write the coordinates of the touch to the div
                if (event.pageX < x * 50 && event.pageY > y * 10) {
                    ballx += 1;
                } else if (event.pageX > x * 50 && event.pageY > y * 10 ) {
                    ballx -= 1;
                }

                console.log(event, x, ballx);

                draw();


            }
            initi();
            draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my code that I wrote:

```
        var lastTime = 0;
        function requestMyAnimationFrame(callback, time)
        {
            var t = time || 16;
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, t - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function(){ callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
        canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
        canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
        var circles = [];
        var mouse =
        {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
        function getCoordinates(x, y)
        {
            return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
        }
        function getRatio(n, d)
        {
            // prevent division by 0
            if (d === 0 || n === 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return n/d;
            }
        }
        function Circle(x,y,d,b,s,c)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.diameter = Math.round(d);
            this.radius = Math.round(d/2);
            this.bounciness = b;
            this.speed = s;
            this.color = c;
            this.deltaX = 0;
            this.deltaY = 0;
            this.drawnPosition = "";
            this.fill = function()
            {
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(this.x+this.radius,this.y+this.radius,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
                context.closePath();
                context.fill();
            }
            this.clear = function()
            {
                context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                this.fill();
            }
            this.draw = function()
            {
                if (this.drawnPosition !== getCoordinates(this.x, this.y))
                {
                    context.fillStyle = this.color;
                    // if commented, the circle will be drawn if it is in the same position
                    //this.drawnPosition = getCoordinates(this.x, this.y);
                    this.fill();
                }
            }
            this.keepInBounds = function()
            {
                if (this.x < 0)
                {
                    this.x = 0;
                    this.deltaX *= -1 * this.bounciness;
                }
                else if (this.x + this.diameter > canvas.width)
                {
                    this.x = canvas.width - this.diameter;
                    this.deltaX *= -1 * this.bounciness;
                }
                if (this.y < 0)
                {
                    this.y = 0;
                    this.deltaY *= -1 * this.bounciness;
                }
                else if (this.y+this.diameter > canvas.height)
                {
                    this.y = canvas.height - this.diameter;
                    this.deltaY *= -1 * this.bounciness;
                }
            }
            this.followMouse = function()
            {
                // deltaX/deltaY will currently cause the circles to "orbit" around the cursor forever unless it hits a wall
                var centerX = Math.round(this.x + this.radius);
                var centerY = Math.round(this.y + this.radius);
                if (centerX < mouse.x)
                {
                    // circle is to the left of the mouse, so move the circle to the right
                    this.deltaX += this.speed;
                }
                else if (centerX > mouse.x)
                {
                    // circle is to the right of the mouse, so move the circle to the left
                    this.deltaX -= this.speed;
                }
                else
                {
                    //this.deltaX = 0;
                }
                if (centerY < mouse.y)
                {
                    // circle is above the mouse, so move the circle downwards
                    this.deltaY += this.speed;
                }
                else if (centerY > mouse.y)
                {
                    // circle is under the mouse, so move the circle upwards
                    this.deltaY -= this.speed;
                }
                else
                {
                    //this.deltaY = 0;
                }
                this.x += this.deltaX;
                this.y += this.deltaY;
                this.x = Math.round(this.x);
                this.y = Math.round(this.y);
            }
        }
        function getRandomDecimal(min, max)
        {
            return Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
        }
        function getRoundedNum(min, max)
        {
            return Math.round(getRandomDecimal(min, max));
        }
        function getRandomColor()
        {
            // array of three colors
            var colors = [];
            // go through loop and add three integers between 0 and 255 (min and max color values)
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                colors[i] = getRoundedNum(0, 255);
            }
            // return rgb value (RED, GREEN, BLUE)
            return "rgb(" + colors[0] + "," + colors[1] + ", " + colors[2] + ")";
        }
        function createCircle(i)
        {
            // diameter of circle
            var minDiameter = 25;
            var maxDiameter = 50;
            // bounciness of circle (changes speed if it hits a wall)
            var minBounciness = 0.2;
            var maxBounciness = 0.65;
            // speed of circle (how fast it moves)
            var minSpeed = 0.3;
            var maxSpeed = 0.45;
            // getRoundedNum returns a random integer and getRandomDecimal returns a random decimal
            var x = getRoundedNum(0, canvas.width);
            var y = getRoundedNum(0, canvas.height);
            var d = getRoundedNum(minDiameter, maxDiameter);
            var c = getRandomColor();
            var b = getRandomDecimal(minBounciness, maxBounciness);
            var s = getRandomDecimal(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
            // create the circle with x, y, diameter, bounciness, speed, and color
            circles[i] = new Circle(x,y,d,b,s,c);
        }
        function makeCircles()
        {
            var maxCircles = getRoundedNum(2, 5);
            for (var i = 0; i < maxCircles; i++)
            {
                createCircle(i);
            }
        }
        function drawCircles()
        {
            var ii = 0;
            for (var i = 0; ii < circles.length; i++)
            {
                if (circles[i])
                {
                    circles[i].draw();
                    ii++;
                }
            }
        }
        function clearCircles()
        {
            var ii = 0;
            for (var i = 0; ii < circles.length; i++)
            {
                if (circles[i])
                {
                    circles[i].clear();
                    ii++;
                }
            }
        }
        function updateCircles()
        {
            var ii = 0;
            for (var i = 0; ii < circles.length; i++)
            {
                if (circles[i])
                {
                    circles[i].keepInBounds();
                    circles[i].followMouse();
                    ii++;
                }
            }
        }
        function update()
        {
            requestMyAnimationFrame(update,10);
            updateCircles();
        }
        function draw()
        {
            requestMyAnimationFrame(draw,1000/60);
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            drawCircles();
        }
        window.addEventListener("load", function()
        {
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e)
            {
                mouse.x = e.layerX || e.offsetX;
                mouse.y = e.layerY || e.offsetY;
            });
            makeCircles();
            update();
            draw();
        });
```